# Modulisomorphism between $R/a\otimes_\mathbb{R} R/b\rightarrow R/(a\cup b)$

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products

I have the following problem:

> Let $R$ be a ring and $a,b\in R$ ideals in $R$. Show:
>   $$R/a\otimes_\mathbb{R} R/b\rightarrow R/(a\cup b)$$
>   $$[x]\otimes[y]\rightarrow[x*y]$$
>   is a welldefined $R$-modulisomorphism.

I have two ideas:

$1.$ I could construct an inverse Isomorphism.

$2.$ I could use the compatibility of tensorproducts and quotients.

The problem is I found no solution using either way. Can someone help me please?

Comment: The ring $R/a\cup b$ should be $R/a+b$.

Comment: Why do you think that is the case? We wrote it down like that two times, so I'm pretty sure it isn't a mistake.

Comment: The union of two ideals is not an ideal (unless one of them is contained in the other). The ideal generated by the union is $a+b$.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I just looked it up and I believe we are just using what I wrote as a notation for what you said,